# Passing options to ffprobe

Tags: ffmpeg, ffprobe

I'm having problem with the ffprobe syntax, getting print format to output default with no keys. There is a nokey option, so I pass in something like this

ffprobe -print_format default nokey

but I get nothing back, not even an error. Is there something wrong with my syntax?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is

-printformat default=nokey=1

Multiple options can be passed in

-print_format default=nokey=1:noprint_wrappers=1

Answer (score 2):

correct syntext wold be

ffprobe -print_format default -skip_frame nokey -i

skip_frame = tells what kind of frame can be skipped to make the ffprobe faster. "nokey" means skip non-key frames (P,B).

but nokey is the default option, and you can "skip" (no pun intended :D ) this option.

Comment: That's not exactly what I was referring to. Its the actual print output which appears as a key value pair ie key="value". There is an option to print the output without the keys, so: value,value,value, that option is called nokey in the documentation. It's the correct to use the second option on -print_format which has me stumped

Comment: print_format can take only these arguments (default, compact, csv, json, xml). if you want to print output only for key_frames you can use -skip_frame nokey.

Comment: I dont think you've understood the question, the correct answer is above.

Comment: well... it might not answer the OP's question - but it does answer mine! :D +1